# Evaluating $\int^1_0x\ \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I find the following integral:

$$\int^1_0x\ \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$

Comment: What have you tried? I mean, M.SE is not an integral calculator. You could try to guess a primitive for the integrand.

Comment: Try substituting $u=1-x^2$.

Comment: If you just want a result, you can use Wolfram: http://tinyurl.com/cm7nok3 It gives also a step-by-step to pro accounts (and 3 free by day)

Comment: It would be better if you had asked the 2nd integral in a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int^1_0x\ \sqrt{1-x^2} = \int^1_0 \ x(1 - x^2)^{1/2}dx$$

Let $u = 1 - x^2.\;$ Then $du = -2x\,dx \iff x\,dx = -\frac 12\,du$

Bounds of integration: At $x = 0, u = 1,\;$ and at $x = 1, u = 0$

Substituting gives us: $$
\begin{align} \int^1_0\ x\ (1-x^2)^{1/2}\,dx 
& =  \int_1^0\ u^{1/2}\left(-\frac 12\,du\right) \\ \\
& = -\frac 12 \int_1^0 \ u^{1/2}\,du \\ \\
& = -\frac 12 u^{3/2}\Big|_1^0 \\ \\
& = \frac 12 u^{3/2}\Big|_0^1 \\ \\
& = \frac 12(1 - 0) = \frac 12
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This certainly deserves a thumbs-up +1

Answer (score 4):

Hints: for a differentiable function $\,f\,$, we have that

$$\int f'(x)\sqrt{f(x)} \, dx=\frac{2}{3}f(x)^{3/2}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\Big(x\,dx\Big)
$$

If you need another hint, here's a dead giveaway, unless you don't know how substitutions work:
$$
\frac 1 2 \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\Big(2x\,dx\Big).
$$